# Jquery: как получить все вложенные элементы, кроме тех, у кого определённый класс

Tags: jquery

Как получить все вложенные элементы, кроме тех, у кого определённый класс?

```
<div class="model-A">
  <div>asda</div>
    <div class="some1">a
        <div class="sub1">a</div>
        <div class="model-B">b
            <div class="some2">b
                <div class="sub2">b</div>
            </div>            
            <div class="some2">b
                <div class="sub2">b</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Например, необходимо получить всё, кроме элемента с классом model-B, или, если быть точнее, надо получить все элементы внутри элемента с классом model-N, где N может быть любым.

Элемент `<div class="model-B">...</div>` получается вложенным, получается при запросе model-A он должен отсутствовать в выборке.

Иначе можно вопрос сформулировать так: получить все элементы, ближайший родитель которых имеет класс model-N.

Чувствую, что решение находится в комбинированном применении селекторов has|not, но мне не удалось добиться результата.

Comment: `.not(".model-B")`

Comment: увы, не прокатит, потому, что если запросить model-A, внутри него всё равно будет содержаться элемент с классом model-B

Comment: ничего непонятно

Comment: добавь пример для твоей разметки, что именно должно быть найдено

Answer (score 0):

Вроде простой вопрос, а нет нормального решения, создал своё:

```js
$.fn.filterWithChildren = function filterWithChildren(selector) {
  let elements = this;

  // Пробегаемся по всем нодам
  elements.each((i, el) => {
    let item = $(el);

    // Если текущий элемен подходит под селектор
    if (!el.matches(selector))
      // То уничтожаем его и, главное, потомков
      elements.splice(i, 1);
    else{
      // Если у очередной ноды есть потомки
      if(item.children().length){
        // Рекурсивно обходим потомков и добавляем очищенные ноды в результат
        elements = elements.add(filterWithChildren.call(item.children(), selector));
      }
    }
  });

  // Возвращаем jQuery-объект, можем продолжить чейнинг
  return elements;
}

// Точка входа
let e = $('.model-A');

// Подсветим все ноды, кроме .model-B и потомков
e.filterWithChildren(':not(.model-B)').css({background: 'lightgreen'});
```

```css
/*
Подсветим фон для .mode-B и его потомков
Если будут найдены эти ноды, то inline-стиль перекроет и покажет своё
*/
.model-B, .model-B *{
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="model-A">
  <div>asda</div>
  <div class="some1">a
    <div class="sub1">a</div>
    <div class="model-B">b
      <div class="some2">b
        <div class="sub2">b</div>
      </div>
      <div class="some2">b
        <div class="sub2">b</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[class*="model-"] *:not(.model-B)` — CSS-селектор, `[class*="model-"]` - находит все элементы, у которых в классе есть совпадение со словом "model-". Пробел означает, что все последующие элементы должны находится внутри. `*` - находит все элементы. К нему добавлен `:not()` - т.е. всё, кроме класса `.model-B` (без кавычек).

```js
$('[class*="model-"] *:not(.model-B)').each(function(){
  $(this).css('border','3px solid orange');
});

// $('[class*="model-"] *:not(.model-B)').css('border','3px solid orange');
```

```css
*{margin: 3px;}
.model-B {border: 3px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="model-A">
  <div>asda</div>
    <div class="some1">a
        <div class="sub1">a</div>
        <div class="model-B">b
            <div class="some2">b
                <div class="sub2">b</div>
            </div>            
            <div class="some2">b
                <div class="sub2">b</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```